# Azure Kubernetes - custom role with delete pods

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, azure-aks

I found on microsoft documentation a yaml that consent to do everything in all resources inside a namespace. I modified this yaml to avoid delete verbs and it works fine:

```
    kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: myaksrole_useraccess
  namespace: mynamespace
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["create", "patch", "get", "update", "list"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources:
  - jobs
  - cronjobs
  verbs: ["create", "patch", "get", "update", "list"]
```

My question is: How I can add delete only for pods resources in this yaml?

Comment: You can try to add to your Role definition next strings for pods: ```- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs: ["delete", "create", "patch", "get", "update", "list"]```

Comment: Hi @Emanuele Any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check the `myaksrole_useraccess` Role from the original definition:

```
kubectl describe role myaksrole_useraccess -n mynamespace
Name:         myaksrole_useraccess
kind: Role
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources       Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------       -----------------  --------------  -----
  *               []                 []              [create patch get update list]
  *.apps          []                 []              [create patch get update list]
  cronjobs.batch  []                 []              [create patch get update list]
  jobs.batch      []                 []              [create patch get update list]
  *.extensions    []                 []              [create patch get update list]
```

Then we can add additional permission for the Pods resource. The updated Role definition is shown below.

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: myaksrole_useraccess
  namespace: mynamespace
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["create", "patch", "get", "update", "list"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources:
  - jobs
  - cronjobs
  verbs: ["create", "patch", "get", "update", "list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs: ["delete", "create", "patch", "get", "update", "list"]
```

Apply the changes:

```
kubectl apply -f myaksrole_useraccess.yaml
```

Check the `myaksrole_useraccess` Role again:

```
kubectl describe role myaksrole_useraccess -n mynamespace
Name:         myaksrole_useraccess
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources       Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------       -----------------  --------------  -----
  *               []                 []              [create patch get update list]
  *.apps          []                 []              [create patch get update list]
  cronjobs.batch  []                 []              [create patch get update list]
  jobs.batch      []                 []              [create patch get update list]
  *.extensions    []                 []              [create patch get update list]
  pods            []                 []              [delete create patch get update list]
```

Comment: Hi all, i was on holiday sorry for delay. Yes it works with:

- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs: ["delete", "create", "patch", "get", "update", "list"]